# Set an event trigger UWP

Tags: c#, windows, triggers, uwp, platform

I'm working with UWP and I wanted to know how could I set an event trigger to execute one background task after the task is registred.

```
        var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
        Debug.WriteLine("Started to Exist");
        builder.Name = exampleTaskName;
        builder.TaskEntryPoint = "RuntimeComponent1.FirstTask";
        var timeTrigger = new TimeTrigger(1, true);
        builder.SetTrigger(timeTrigger);
        builder.Register();
```

(My code)

Thanks

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: I can't do this, the background event never start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the code you've posted, you've set wrong `FreshnessTime` when you initialized the new instance of a time event trigger. The `FreshnessTime` should be larger than 15 minutes or at least equal to 15 minutes.

> **Note**  If *FreshnessTime* is set to less than 15 minutes, an exception is thrown when attempting to register the background task.

For more info, please see [TimeTrigger.TimeTrigger constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.timetrigger.timetrigger.aspx) or [TimeTrigger.FreshnessTime property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.timetrigger.freshnesstime). And there is also a official [Background task sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundTask) in GitHub you can refer to.

Comment: Is there any way to execute the event in less time? I want to do it +- when the app launch.

Comment: @Onelio There is no way to shorten the time. But if you want to do something when the app launch, you can try with [Application.OnLaunched method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.onlaunched.aspx).

Comment: How could I implement this in the code to execute the event?

Comment: You should go and place your code in OnLaunched in App.Xaml.Cs

Comment: @Onelio I'm not sure what you actually want to do, so it's hard to suggest you how to implement this. As Jerrak0s said, usually, you can place your code in `OnLaunched` method in App.xaml.cs. If you still has problems, I'd suggest you ask a new question that clarifies your specific problem and provides details to highlight exactly what you need.